# A macro failed to use decltype(X) in g++

Tags: c++, macros

I've written a macro --- swapMacro and its 2 sub macros as below.

```
#define swapMacro( X, Y) swap_Macro1( X, Y, decltype(X) )
#define regTMP tmp ## __LINE__ ## __FILE__
#define swap_Macro1( X, Y, ARG_TYPE ) \
do { \
  register ARG_TYPE regTMP; \
  swap_Macro2( (X), (Y), regTMP); \
} while( 0);
#define swap_Macro2( X, Y, T) \
{ \
  (T)= (X);\
  (X)= (Y);\
  (Y)= (T);\
}
```

And here is the code to test them.

```
int a= 110;
int b= 220;
{
   register int t;
   swap_Macro2 ( a, b, t);  // works perfect, only 2 mem/r + 2 mem/w operations
}
swap_Macro1 ( a, b, int ); // works, as same as swap_Macro2
swapMacro ( a, b); // this one works if cflag -std=c++11 is set

int *A= new int(10);
int *B= new int(10);
A[0]= 330;
B[0]= 440;
swapMacro ( (A[0]), B[0]); // failed, even -std=c++11 is set
swapMacro ( A[0], B[0]); // failed, even -std=c++11 is set. However, the solution provide by Anton Savin solve it
```

But if I use Visual C++ 2010 to do that again, all 3 macros work, although they all need 3 mem/r and 3 mem/w operations ( watched from the debugger windows).
I wonder if there is any proper syntax to write swapMacro(a,b) for use of g++ ?

Comment: What version of GCC are you using? What is the command line? Have you specified `-std=c++11` or `-std=c++14`?

Comment: Why not use inline function instead ?

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. When posting questions about things which do not work, it is always helpful to post any error message. In this case, what is g++ telling you about why it doesn't compile?

Comment: Use `std::swap`. With modern compilers, that probably results in ZERO operations. The compiler just knows that what you called `a` before is called `b` afterwards and vice versa. That's compile-time bookkeeping.

Comment: @AntonSavin, I use gcc 4.8.4 with flag -std=c++11 on.

Comment: @MatthewWalton, the error message of swapMacro: register decltype((X)) regTMP, regTMP declared as reference but not initialized

Comment: [Everything works for me](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/c727243528cd0e41). Probably your actual code is different, please show it.

Comment: Templates templates templates templates templates templates templates templates templates templates. Use them. Or std::swap.

Comment: @Rei, I had tried using templates before, all I can do is to produce a new sub-routine, and use it by function-call, that uses more operations than 6.

Comment: @AntonSavin, I just tried and yes the posted codes works if the flag -std=c++11 set. I have to check the differences of my real code, I'll post the result later.

Comment: std::swap is implemented using templates, not macros. Avoid preprocessor macros at all cost. Or use lisp.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As I wrote in a comment, your code [works for me](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/c727243528cd0e41). However, I believe the reason for the error is that you added extra parentheses somewhere, like this:

```
swapMacro ((a), b);
```

In this case, `decltype(X)` becomes `decltype((a))` and that is not `int` now but `int&`.

To fix it you can change `swapMacro` definition by

```
#define swapMacro( X, Y) swap_Macro1( X, Y, std::remove_reference<decltype(X)>::type )
```

That said, I don't quite understand the purpose of all these macros and why you don't just use `std::swap()`.

Comment: Thank you for the reply, std::swap uses 3 mem/r and 3 mem/w, I wonder if using 2 mem/r and 2 mem/w is achievable for swapping variables of fundamental type, why should I use it :-) . I'll check my codes later and try yours.